How to run an exe on a remote server with task planer?
I want to run a remote exe with task planer. For security reasons I have created a new user with limited priviliges in our AD. If I log in with the user I can run the app without any issues, however, it asks/warns me always if I am sure to run a remote exe. I wrapped the exe within a local powershell script to catch the error. It tells me that the access was denied. How can I solve this issue? Preferrably only for one user and one remote server
